# Replace . (period) by , (comma) in numbers

Tags: macros, formatting

I pass a bunch of numbers into a custom command defined via `\newcommand{\mycmd}[1]{...}`:

```
\mycmd{1.12}
\mycmd{5.32}
```

`\mycmd` uses the number to draw a certain figure. On top of that, I would like to print the number in `\mycmd`, but with a comma instead of a decimal point: `1,12`, `5,32`.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure the `siunitx` package is the way to go because it will catch all corner cases. Out of curiosity, here is a simple solution that uses TeX's pattern matching capabilities.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\def\usecomma#1.#2{#1,#2}
\newcommand\mycmd[1]{\usecomma #1}
\begin{document}
    \obeylines
    1.12 $\to$ \mycmd{1.12}
    5.32 $\to$ \mycmd{5.32}
\end{document}
```

Note that it won't work if you pass an argument that has no dot, like `\mycmd{2}`. Is this too simple and there is something else that I have overlooked?

Comment: Good answer. My first idea was also to do it by hand like this, but then remembered `siunitx`. You could add some fall-back code to catch the case where no `.` is included. Also here `#2` is not required, a simple `\def\usecomma#1.{#1,}` would be enough.

Comment: Why are you using `\obeylines`?

Comment: @Martin: thanks for your comments on my code and I like the idea just to match the first part including the dot. The `\obeylines` was just pure laziness on my part to quickly display examples line by line. (I should refrain from doing this in public.) I had no immediate idea for the fallback code - case selection is a part where I struggle a lot in TeX.

Comment: Here some code which would catch the missing dot case. Then `#1` ends in `\empty` which shouldn't be a problem and could be removed if so: `\def\usecomma#1.#2\empty#3\relax{#1,#2}
\newcommand\mycmd[1]{\usecomma #1\empty.\empty\relax}`

Answer (score 10):

This can be done using the `siunitx` package. Use the `\num` macro with the `output-decimal-marker={,}` option. The option can also be set globally using `\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num[output-decimal-marker={,}]{123.45}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine in an isolated setting, thanks. But the `siunitx` package does not seem to work with the solution @Bruno Le Floch suggested in my question "Control order of columns in table": http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13907/control-order-of-columns-in-table/13930#13930 :(

Comment: @Frank: Sorry, I can't see the connection. You would have to show how you use both together.

Comment: I take @Bruno Le Floch code and add `\usepackage{siunitx}` -> error. The problem probably goes beyond this question...

Comment: @Frank: That's only because both define the `s` column character. Simply use a different one in Bruno's code and it will work.

Answer (score 6):

There's a number of possible solutions; two of them: 1) Use the [isonums](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/isonums) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{isonums}
\newcommand\mycmd[1]{$#1$}

\begin{document}
\mycmd{5.32}
\end{document}
```

2) If you are using `babel`, you could use the `spanish` option and select it to typeset your number (the `spanish` option, by default uses the comma as the decimal separator):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish,english]{babel}

\newcommand\mycmd[1]{$\selectlanguage{spanish}#1$}

\begin{document}
\mycmd{5.32}
\end{document}
```

Of course, if `spanish` is the only option for babel, then `\selectlanguage{spanish}` is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [`numprint` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/numprint):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}

\begin{document}
    \obeylines
    1.12 $\to$ \numprint{1.12}
    5.32 $\to$ \numprint{5.32}
\end{document}
```

[image]