# Comma as decimal marker with siunitx (Spanish usage)

Tags: punctuation, siunitx, spanish

I'm using `siunitx` to input some big numbers and units in my document.

Is there a way to make the output of `\num{3.14}` be "3,13" instead of "3.13"? In Spanish, we use the first one.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18673 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13949

Comment: @Andrey: A tip: If you copy and paste the entire URL of a tex.sx question in your comment, it'll automatically get shortened _and_ display the question when you mouseover the link, e.g. http:// tex.stackexchange .com /questions/18673/german-language-use-of-comma-in-numbers (w/o spaces) becomes http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18673/german-language-use-of-comma-in-numbers

Comment: @Tomas: Wait ... did you actually want to get 3,1_3_ when you input 3.1_4_?

Comment: @Tomas:  the ISO norm 80000-1, accepts both the period and the comma as decimal separator, and in the most recent version of the *Ortografía de la lengua española*, our Academia recommends the use of the period as decimal separator, although the comma is still accepted. More information here: [La marca decimal](http://www.tex-tipografia.com/marca_decimal.html)

Comment: @Gonzalo: Thanks for the info, i did't know the period is allowed as well.  The problem is that using `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` all the number inputs with decimal in math mode get a `,` regardless the code being `.` or `,`. So, I'd have to change an option of the label package to make it display periods. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Tomas: After loading `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` you can use `\decimalpoint` to use the point as decimal separator, and `\decimalcomma` to revert to the comma.

Comment: @Gonzalo: In `siunitx` I tend to aim for consistency with current publishing practice. What is the situation 'on the ground' at the moment: `.` or `,`?

Comment: @Tomas: `\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}` should be enough.

Comment: So the recommendation would be `.` for the decimal marker and  `\cdot` for exponents. I guess that means `\,` as the digit-grouping separator. What about between units (`\,` and `\cdot` seem to be the common choices)?

Comment: @Joseph: as I said before, both are accepted by the international norm I mentioned, and recently the Real Academia Española recommended using the period instead of the comma, although the latter is still accepted.

Comment: @Joseph: I don't have any problem using `.` instead of `,` for decimal since everyone would understand it anyway. This should be something universal and i think it's better to use @egreg solution and leave `siunitx` with default settings.

Comment: @Joseph: between units, the fine space is to be used, and never a dot, although in practice, most people tend to use the dot. The norm, however, dictates a fine space to separate the groups of three digits: as in 3\,123\,456

Comment: @Joseph: of couse, all my remarks are only valid for Spanish.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Is that the same space i should use for separate the number from the unit? As in: `\num{85+30i}\;\si\ohm`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

At the most basic

```
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}
```

will do the job.

The package includes some pre-defined 'locales' for different typographic traditions, for example

```
\sisetup{locale = FR}
```

To date, I've not had details on Spanish conventions, so do not have an `ES` locale (there is more than just the decimal marker to worry about). In particular, what do you use for the exponent, `1.23 \times 10^{3}` or `1.23 \cdot 10^{3}` (or ...).

Comment: Thanks. We use `\cdot` for exponents. `\times` is more used for operations like vector products. Oh, i almost forgot. We use period for thousand separation.

Comment: @Thomas: How do you write a 3D point (spherical coordinate system), for example, (21.3,30.5,10) in Spanish?

Comment: @Joseph I think a single locale for Spanish is not possible. Very likely we need ES_es, ES_mx, ES_ar, and so on.

Comment: @JavierBezos No, that would be confusing locale and language. `ES` would be Spain, I guess `MX` is Mexico, and so on. (For example, `FR` does not mean the text is in French, it means that the typography follows the conventions in use in France.)

Comment: You can also load the package with this option: `\usepackage[locale=FR]{siunitx}`

Comment: Hi, how can I write a custom locale, inside the document?

Comment: @JosephWright This forces both ``$\num{3.14}$`` and ``$\num{3,14}$`` to show up as ``3,14``. Is it possible to use both ``.`` and ``,`` as decimal separators and display the input faithfully? That is, ``$\num{3.14}$`` gives ``3.14``, and ``$\num{3,14}$`` gives ``3,14``. If it is, how? (May I suggest adding this information to the answer here to avoid a new question? :) )

Comment: This solution does not seem to work with R input. If the input comes from R then siunitx results with the error message like `! Package siunitx Error: Invalid number '\protect \text  {0,001}'.` and if the input is direct then siunitx works just fine. Why is that?