# How to make temperatures with decimal comma?

Tags: siunitx

I was asked to write a document where I have to put temperatures like -51,4 degrees celcius. How can I do that in LaTeX? I tried

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
...
\SI{-51{,}4}{\celsius}
```

but it turns the comma to the dot.

Comment: this question may be helpful: [Comma as decimal marker with siunitx (Spanish usage)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20877/579).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\begin{document}

\SI{-51,4}{\celsius} \SI{-51.4}{\celsius}

\end{document}
```