# How to write non-numerical content into an S-type column from siunitx package?

Tags: tables, siunitx

What is wrong with this table? I think there is something wrong with `$\si{\degree}$`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!!]
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c cS[table-format=3.1]c}

De  &V (km) &S ($\si{\degree}$)     &P (min)    &Per (dny)\\
\hline
A &                 840     &   98,7&   101,5&  0,07048\\
B &                 785     &   98,7&   101,4&  0,07041\\
C   &   775-790&    98,6&   100,4&  0,06972\\
D       &   612-640&    98,0&   97,1&   0,06743\\

\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, the problem is not there

Comment: The problem is `Per (dny)`, if you replace it by `\multicolumn{1}{r}{Per (dny)}` there is no error. The reason is that you cannot use such stuff in an `S` column.

Comment: @marmot We only need `{Per (dny)}`.

Comment: @JouleV Yes, that's simpler.

Comment: @marmot It reminded me of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/481944/156344) :))

Comment: @JouleV Yes, clearly a duplicate. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are making the last column of your table as a SI (`S`) column, so you must wrap non-number contents in that column inside braces. Btw `h!!` is nonsense.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}

\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c c S[table-format=3.1]c}
De  & V (km) & S (\si{\degree}) & P (min)    &{Per (dny)}\\
\hline
A & 840     & 98,7 & 101.5 & 0,07048\\
B & 785     & 98,7 & 101.4 & 0,07041\\
C & 775-790 & 98,6 & 100.4 & 0,06972\\
D & 612-640 & 98,0 & 97.1  & 0,06743
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However it will change the commas to dots in the last column. To avoid this, read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20877/156344).

It seems to me that you are trying to make the second last column to be a SI column, so you should place `S[table-format=3.1]` somewhere else. My final answer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[locale=FR]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c c S[table-format=3.1]c c}
De  & V (km) & S (\si{\degree}) & {P (min)}    & Per (dny)\\
\hline
A & 840     & 98,7 & 101,5 & 0,07048\\
B & 785     & 98,7 & 101,4 & 0,07041\\
C & 775-790 & 98,6 & 100,4 & 0,06972\\
D & 612-640 & 98,0 & 97,1  & 0,06743
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, take care of the last column. I intentionally keep it, but you may want to reduce its size.

Comment: Thank you very much and what is wrong with using `\Xhline{1.2pt}` in the table?

Comment: @LukášAltman Nothing wrong. I can use it as usual, but I don't recommend it though. Just remember loading `makecell` package

Answer (score 3):

i would wrote your table narrower:

[image]

and for last three columns use `S` column type:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}% mathtools load `amsmath
\usepackage[locale=FR]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\begin{tabular}{l c
                S[table-format=2.1]
                S[table-format=3.1]
                S[table-format=1.5]}
De  & V (km) & S {(\si{\degree})} & {P (min)}    & {Per (dny)}\\
    \hline
A & 840     & 98,7 & 101,5 & 0,07048\\
B & 785     & 98,7 & 101,4 & 0,07041\\
C & 775-790 & 98,6 & 100,4 & 0,06972\\
D & 612-640 & 98,0 & 97,1  & 0,06743
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

note curly braces around column headers in `S` columns!