# File cannot be found error

Tags: pdftex, pdf, compiling

Can't find a pdf file of the document anymore, pdf does not compile, after entering the following

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
    pointlessnumbers, 
    %draft,
    parskip=half,
    automark
        ]{scrartcl}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 

\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx} 


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{titling}

\usepackage{subfigure}


\usepackage{hyperref}


    \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
    \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
    \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
    \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 

    \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
    \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
    
    \newcommand{\xdot}{\cdot}
    \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}
    
%Titelseite
\title{m}
\author{b}

%Dokument
\begin{document}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\clearpage
%Inhaltsverzeichnis
%\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
%Hauptdokument
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
\ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
%\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
\ofoot{\upshape\thepage}

\begin{equation}
tan\phi=\frac{{\frac{1}{\omega L_M}+\frac{\omega L_{\sigma}\gamma^2 I_2^2}{U_1^2}}{\frac{1}{R_{FE}}+
+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{U_1^2}{\gamma^2 I_2^2}-\omega^2  L_{\sigma}^2}\gamma^2 I_2^2}{U_1^2}}

\label{eq:80}
\end{equation}

Dies ist äquivalent zu 

\begin{equation}
\phi=arctan(Gl.\ref{eq:80})
\label{eq:5}
\end{equation}

--------------------------

?ab hier eigene Werte eingeben:
In dem Fall ist\\
A=$\omega L_M=2\pi f L_M=2\pi$


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example stops at `! LaTeX Error: File \`scrpage2.sty' not found`

Comment: but the main error is`Runaway argument?
{{\frac {1}{\omega L_M}+\frac {\omega L_{\sigma }\gamma ^2 I_2^2}{U_1\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \frac .
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> cc340
         
? `    count your`{` and`}`

Comment: it was the bracket!

Comment: yes, as tex reported, never ignore error messages

Answer (score 0):

Your document has several errors that you need to address in order for it to compile.

### 1. Replace deprecated `scrpage2` package

The `scrpage2` package referenced in the preamble (`\usepackage{scrpage2}`) has been deprecated and should be replaced with `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}`. According to the [package documentation](http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script-obsolete/scrpage2-obsolete.pdf):

> The
> package is deprecated and should not be used any longer.
> You can very easily replace it by the KOMA -Script package
> scrlayer-scrpage that is documented in the English and the
> German KOMA -Script guide.

This question has additional advice on replacing the `scrpage2` package: [LaTeX Error: File `scrpage2.sty' not found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/541766/latex-error-file-scrpage2-sty-not-found)

### 2. Use `\sisetup` instead of `siunitx` to control decimal style

`[decimalsymbol=comma]` is not a valid option for `siunitx`. To change the decimal style, use the `\sisteup` command: [Comma as decimal marker with siunitx (Spanish usage)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20877/comma-as-decimal-marker-with-siunitx-spanish-usage)

You also import `siunitx` more than once, so you should delete the extra reference and just have `\usepackage{siunitx}` followed by the appropriate `\sisetup` command.

### 3. Use correct number of braces in equations

The equation labeled 80 doesn't have enough braces to properly enclose the equation. There's a lot going on so I'm honestly not sure what you are trying to do there, but one way to troubleshoot is to break each set of braces into separate indented lines so you can confirm each term is correctly enclosed. In particular I would check that each fraction has two sets of braces (`\frac{}{}`) and that the terms under the radical are enclosed (`\sqrt{}`).

Comment: Did you try "change `\usepackage{scrpage2`} to `\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}`" with the supplied document and see if it results in a PDF file? (I assume you did not)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes and nothing changed

Comment: @NirvanicUniverse my question was to chaya asking if they had tested the answer. Your document has multiple errors, as tex reports, and this one is not theone prventing the pdf being made.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle fair point, my compiler stopped on the scrpage2 error and I didn't try to recompile after fixing it. I will update my answer, thank you!