# Compare numbers with comma as decimal points

Tags: formatting, conditionals

I want to check whether a number `\a` (read from a file) is smaller than zero using `ifthenelse`:

```
\ifthenelse{\a<5}{smaller}{not smaller}
```

This works fine when a is in the format `-1`. In the file commas (`,`) are used as decimal separators, so `\ifthenelse` fails.

Any ideas on how to compare such a number of format `-1,23`?

PS: I know `siunitx` could probably do it, but it seems to conflict with `csvsimple`, so it is not an option.

Comment: The standard test of `\ifthenelse` compares only *integer* numbers. You may try `\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\a pt<0pt}}{true}{false}` which should be indifferent to the decimal separator (comma or period).

Comment: You are right.
`\lengthtest` seems to only work with `,` for testing if `\a` is larger/smaller than zero (not other values). But this is already very good.

Comment: I don't fully understand this comment. You can also compare with other values, for instance `\lengthtest{\a pt<5pt}`.

Comment: You can also use `\ifdim \a pt<2,5pt x \else y \fi` (note the `pt` after the numbers to be tested).

Comment: The problem is the comma. English (and TeX as well) use dot as a seperator. We would need to know more, but [the first answer here (link)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13949/http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14004/11002) can be easily reverted to replace `,` by `.`.

Comment: The combination of `\lengthtest` and using `,` for the constant value as well worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A decimal number can always be input either with the comma or the period, when TeX's length tests are concerned.

On the other hand, the standard test for `\ifthenelse` compares *integer* numbers. So we need to do differently:

```
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\a pt < 0pt}}{smaller}{not smaller}
```

will do, because `\a` will expand to the decimal number and adding the unit point to it will give a legitimate length to be compared with `0pt`.

One is not forced to use `0pt`: any length is good. So if the test must compare if the given number is less than `1.23`,

```
\ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\a pt < 1.23pt}}{smaller}{not smaller}
```

will do. This, of course, will compare correctly numbers with a short decimal part (TeX compares correctly up to the fourth decimal digit, the fifth may not be recognized because of the internal binary arithmetic with truncation).

Either commas or periods for delimiting the decimal part can be used safely.

Comment: As usual, a very useful answer for more than one LaTeX-user! Thank you, egreg!