# table from pdf to latex

Tags: tables, beamer, pdf

Ciao guys 
I am making a presentation using beamer. It is based on an online research article. Let's say there's a pdf file with a table consisting of 4 columns and 5 rows. What would be the easiest way (besides manual) to get just the rows 1-5 and columns 1-3?

Comment: I am unsure I am parsing this question right -- can you please explain your last sentence? Regards,

Comment: @Abhimanyu Do you mean to copy-paste the data from the table?

Comment: @JosephWright: Yes indeed not the entire table but a part of it. Not only the data but if possible the format and layout as well

Comment: @KannappanSampath:I think row 1-3 would be better put

Comment: If you question is that you have a table in LaTeX with 4 columns and 5 rows, but want the table to only print the first three columns (without changing the table's data), then you can do this with [the `collcell` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell).  See for example [Control order of columns in table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13907/control-order-of-columns-in-table), and [How to execute command on every table column](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59785/how-to-execute-command-on-every-table-column).

Comment: Although I'm often surprised on this site, I'll be surprised if your question (and comment) can be answered in a non-trivial way, if at all.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is -- you must do the table by hand.

The pdf file is like a cake -- you can't identify the ingredients.

Answer (score 2):

If the range of rows and columns you want to import is contiguous, a possible solution, not that I am recommending it, could be to use `\includegraphics` to insert part of your pdf, with appropiate values for `trim` and `clip` option.

For details about `trim` option you can see my answer to the question [How to trim after an overpic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65011/how-to-trim-after-an-overpic/65014#65014)

Answer (score 0):

You can import the PDF to Word, then copy the rows you desire to Google sheets and finally use the [LatexKit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370738) add-on to export them to Tabular.