# How to transform Google docs tables into Latex Tables?

Tags: tables, conversion, csv

I usually do all of my tables using Google Docs spreadsheet. This is a good and quick way to organize information and create quick tables.

Now I am writing a document in Latex and I would like to port the tables.

I tried downloading the sheet as a CSV file and then using the `csvsimple` package to convert it into latex, but this has several faults (does not copy cell borders, does not respect page width and height, etc), and in the end with all the configurations it is almost just as complex as creating the tables myself.

I recognize some of the problems are inherent to the CSV file format (no package can *guess* information that the CSV file does not contain), so I was wondering: Is any other way of quickly porting my Google Doc tables to latex?

[Here is a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AuUP5lxiQ9AodHdnaEY0YkxFa2hkSnkzRDQzN2dUMnc&single=true&gid=4&output=html) with a simple set of three tables and a graph that I would like to port to latex:

[image]

Comment: A bit clunky, but I suppose you could download the sheet as an .ods file, open it in LibreOffice, and use [calc2latex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56526/586) to generate a LaTeX table.

Comment: Extra information: Google Docs has an HTML export option. (That's its native-ish format, after all.)  Could this be used with pandoc?  (Need to run…)

Comment: Did you take a look at [`pgfplotstable`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable)? That provides options to convert plaintext data files to tables. Cell borders are not exported to csv, but usually a good table needs no borders ;) If you want more detailed advice please post some sample data and a picture of what you want it to look like.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Clunky in deed. It does not keep the table inside the pages limits and the generated code is very basic at best.

Comment: @SeanAllred: pandoc? Never heard of it. Guess I will have to do some research.

Comment: @hugovdberg: My tables have borders and I want to keep them that way :D. As for sample data, you mean you want me to post a Google Docs table?

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Part of a csv file with an example what you want it to look like would be enough I guess.

Comment: Open with `gnumeric`. The problem is that then generated source code is too complex for my taste. I prefer export the table as a LaTeX fragment and lost all the format. It is better start with a clean `aaa & bbb & ccc \\ ...` and lost all the vertical lines (evil) and horizontal lines as well. Add a table environment, one `\toprule`, one  `\bottomrule` one  `\midrule` of the `booktabs` package is no too complex and this way I obtain a clean source code and a pretty table.

Comment: Added an example !

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is exactly the same problem I and my classmates were having when writing our lab reports on Experimental Physics. Since we work in groups it's great to have data on the cloud. The problem was converting sometimes dozens of tables to Latex...

So, I and a classmate of mine came up with [LatexKit](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/latexkit/716178627426), a google sheets add-on that creates and exports to your Google Drive a text file containing the tabular environment of a given table.

For your case, this won't handle page width or height, nor copy the exact borders you have configured (although there is a way to overcome this, keep reading), but it can help you get started with little trouble and systematically for multiple tables.

This add-on is developed using [Google apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) so, unfortunately, the lack of some features is not easily overcomeable.

It does, however, help a lot when converting tables from Google Sheets to Latex

It has some additional features that could help you or someone else in the future.

**Current Features:**

- Handles multirow and multicolumn environment using the multirow package
- Handles uncertainties notation $\pm$ (especially useful to us at experimental physics)
- Although it does not replicate your table's borders it has some templates for border configuration (like hlines everywhere or vertical lines everywhere)
- Allows you to configure and export multiple tables at a time using the [Named Range feature](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en).

**Features that can or will be implemented (given the time and will of the community):**

- Configure the table to have the same alignments as in your Spreadsheet
- Handle different font styles like **bold**, *italic*, etc...
- And a lot more, you just have to pitch us the idea! Reach us either trough [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/latexkit/) or e-mail: latexkit.dev@gmail.com

**Here's LatexKit in action**

This is the table on the spreadsheet:

[image]

This is the exact code produced by LatexKit using the template 'grid':

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
 \hline
Time (h) & Temperature (C)   \\ \hline
12       & 19.5 $\pm$ 0.4    \\ \hline
13       & 20.3 $\pm$ 0.6    \\ \hline
14       & 21.8 $\pm$ 0.7    \\ \hline
15       & 20.9 $\pm$ 0.6    \\ \hline
16       & 19.7 $\pm$ 0.4    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

This is the result when compiled in Latex:

[image]

**This is really a project to the community so we would gladly take your advice to improve!**

Comment: Thanks for the extension, but why it has so broad permissions? `See, edit, create, and delete all of your Google Drive files`

Comment: @diraria, from what I gathered, the permissions are requested automatically by Google. It needs those permissions because of some of our features that involve the creation of .tex files to your google drive. However, the extension does not interact with any of the user's files apart from the ones it creates. We know this is not optimal but it's something we haven't been able to tackle yet

Comment: Extension seems to be promising. But asking for too many permissions that I can't risk. Thus I downloaded the data as a CSV file and used http://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables to generate the Latex.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Spread-LaTeX](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/spreadlatex/218144906748.), a simple add-on which was designed for converting a Google spreadsheet table to a LaTeX table or a LaTeX table to a Google Spreadsheet table.

Comment: Users seem not to be able to install this add-on at the time of writing this comment.

Comment: Is there any error? I don't receive any error for this add-on error.

Comment: ERROR: Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app
This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In.

Comment: The app has been verified. Hope you enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google docs extension [LatexKit](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/latexkit/716178627426)

Comment: Rather than just providing a link, can you give an example of this in action.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the most non-invasive way would be to download the table as a CSV and then use a trusted tool for conversion of CSV into a LaTeX table.
I haven't personally used this, but you can try [csv2latex](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/csv2latex.1.html).