# ShareLaTeX - Text formatted as table conversion into LaTeX table

Tags: tables

I want to convert a plain text formatted as a table into a LaTeX table. I have a routing table I wanted to include in my file but here it is:

```
Routing Tables: Public
         Destinations : 10       Routes : 10       

Destination/Mask    Proto   Pre  Cost      Flags NextHop         Interface

       10.0.1.0/24  Direct  0    0           D   10.0.1.1        LoopBack0
       10.0.1.1/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       LoopBack0
     10.0.1.255/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       LoopBack0
      10.0.12.0/24  Direct  0    0           D   10.0.12.1       GigabitEthernet
0/0/0
```

I tried manually to create a table but I have to include many like this and it would take too long, I also tried consider it as code using `\begin{listing}... \end{listing}` but doesn't format well either.

I was wondering if is there was any tool or suggested command.

PS: 
Also the last line "0/0/0" should be part of the previous one.

Comment: May be this might help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165918/how-to-transform-google-docs-tables-into-latex-tables ? I think you could pull the same work-around mentioned there

Comment: there are tools but really with a any text editor it should only be a few seconds work to change each run of white space to `&`, add a `\\ ` at the end of the lines and then add some `\begin{tabular}` markup that gives the possibility for hand tuning the layout and will give better, more understandable markup and output than an automated generation.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to include the output of some program and not to adapt the information, you can include it `verbatim`, either by copying it to the LaTeX file or by keeping it in a separate file that is included verbatim. Depending on the text width you may have to adapt the font size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\noindent
{\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
Routing Tables: Public
         Destinations : 10       Routes : 10       

Destination/Mask    Proto   Pre  Cost      Flags NextHop         Interface

       10.0.1.0/24  Direct  0    0           D   10.0.1.1        LoopBack0
       10.0.1.1/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       LoopBack0
     10.0.1.255/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       LoopBack0
      10.0.12.0/24  Direct  0    0           D   10.0.12.1       GigabitEthernet 0/0/0
\end{verbatim}
}

% Alternatively, load the data from a file.

\noindent
{\footnotesize
\verbatiminput{routing.txt}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The file `routing.txt` contains the following lines:

```
Routing Tables: Public
         Destinations : 10       Routes : 10       

Destination/Mask    Proto   Pre  Cost      Flags NextHop         Interface

       10.0.1.0/24  Direct  0    0           D   10.0.1.1        LoopBack0
       10.0.1.1/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       LoopBack0
     10.0.1.255/32  Direct  0    0           D   127.0.0.1       LoopBack0
      10.0.12.0/24  Direct  0    0           D   10.0.12.1       GigabitEthernet 0/0/0
```